# Linq: How to transform rows to columns with a count (Crosstab data)?

Tags: c#, linq, crosstab

I think I need a way to perform a pivot or crosstab using C# and Linq with an indeterminate number of columns.  However, I will add some beginning detail to see where it goes.

< Beginning detail >

Imagine a table that has two fields:

```
string EventName;
Datetime WhenItHappend;
```

We want to generate a report like the example below where we group by the EventName, then have a series of columns that calculate some date and time frame count.  The difficulty is obviously a variable number of columns.

<kbd>Sport</kbd>   <kbd>Jan 2010</kbd><kbd>Jan 2009</kbd><kbd>Feb 2010</kbd><kbd>Feb 2009</kbd>
<kbd>Basketball</kbd>    <kbd>26</kbd>      <kbd>18</kbd>      <kbd>23</kbd>      <kbd>16</kbd>  
<kbd>Hockey</kbd>        <kbd>28</kbd>      <kbd>19</kbd>      <kbd>25</kbd>      <kbd>18</kbd>  
<kbd>Swimming</kbd>      <kbd>52</kbd>      <kbd>45</kbd>      <kbd>48</kbd>      <kbd>43</kbd>

The customer can create any number of named event counters for a report.  The functions are always the same: "Name", "begin", "end".

**Any way to assemble this as a single linq IQueryable result in C#?**

< End Beginning detail >

As far as SQL goes, I tried creating a date range table {TimeFrameName, begin, end} and joined that to the above table where begin <= whenItHappened and whenItHappened <= end, which produced a nice set of {EventName, TimeFrameName} then did a count(*), but was still left with how to transform the data, making the rows in to columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a class / SQL row

```
class Thing
{
    public string EventName;
    public DateTime WhenItHappend;
}
```

and you want to group by EventName and WhenItHappened.Month

```
// make a collection and add some Things to it
var list = new List<Thing>();
list.Add(new Thing(){ .... });
// etc

var groups = list.GroupBy(t => new { t.WhenItHappend.Month, t.EventName } );
```

Now you essentially have a 2 dimensional array of collections.  You can iterate through these on Month / EventName to get the counts of the items in each collection, which is what you want to display in your table.

```
foreach (var row in groups.GroupBy(g => g.Key.EventName))
{
    foreach (var month in row.GroupBy(g => g.Key.Month))
    {
        var value = month.Count();
    }
}
```

The GroupBy operator returns a collection of groups, where each group contains a Key and a subset of the original list that match the specified Key.  If you specify a 2 dimensional Key, you can treat the result as a 2 dimensional array of collections.

GroupBy is a very powerful operator!

Comment: Pretty cool.  I like the nested calculators.  So I am thinking that each named time frame the customer selects would be a separate collection like you have above in "groups", then join the collections together based on the EventName?

Comment: I would probably make a collection of date ranges, and then group by the EventName and the appropriate date range.  i.e. dateRanges.Where(d => d.StartDate < t.WhenItHappened && d.EndDate > t.WhenItHappened).