# Select a two-way table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have three MySql tables:

**Students** - StudentId, StudentName

**Assessments** - AssessmentId, AssessmentName

**Results** - StudentId, AssessmentId, Grade

**I can't predetermine the number of students or assessments, as these are created by users.**

How can I select a two-way table, showing the results of all students' assessments (which will have an unpredetermined number of rows and columns):

```
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|User    |Test A   |Test B   |Test C   |Test D   |Test E   |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|Alex    |A        |A        |C        |Null     |F        |
|Ben     |Null     |D        |A        |Null     |Null     |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

I am looking to do this either in a SQL select, or using LINQ to Entities in ASP.NET, if that has an efficient method for achieving the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in a single SQL query. You will need a function that will generate a result-set with variable columns and then make a select from it.

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible within a MySql command? Or do I need to make several database calls?

Comment: You will need 1 select to return the number of cols (Tests) and another to make a cursor from it.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: SELECT id from Assessments - the first query. After this you can create a temp table having assessments as columns. And then with a simple query like SELECT StudentName, AssessmentId, Grade FROM Results, Students; you can populate the temporary table. In my opinion, this will not be to easy to accomplish, but is doable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a pivot or crosstab directly in MySQL. You could select the results ordered by user, test then rearrange them into a cross tab. See e.g.

[Is it possible to Pivot data using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq)

[Linq: How to transform rows to columns with a count (Crosstab data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405249/linq-how-to-transform-rows-to-columns-with-a-count-crosstab-data)